# Partition table and partition elimination

Tags: performance, partitioning

I've got a large table of about 300 millones rows. My enviorment is Sql server azure.

There are constant insert to this table And some updates.

The quieres for this table are only for data in the past month.

My question is:
if I partition by a datepart ,lets say a month,and adjust my quries to only query data for the last two month.
Will it use the partition and only query the last partition made?
Is this partition eliminatión?
And should I implement it performance wise?

Answer (score 1):

> I've got a large table of about 300 millones rows.

Ok, it's a decent size, nothing concerning though.

> My question is: if I partition by a datepart ,lets say a month,and adjust my quries to only query data for the last two month. Will it use the partition and only query the last partition made?

No. Your partitions would be monthly, but you say you would query for 2 months of data. So it would minimally need to look at the last 2 partitions.

> Is this partition eliminatión?

If things shake out correctly that you only get exactly the partitions of data you need, then yes. For more information on partition elimination, please see this [Kendra Little article](https://littlekendra.com/course/why-table-partitioning-does-not-speed-up-query-performance-with-exception/partition-elimination/) about it.

> And should I implement it performance wise?

Nope. Partitioning isn't a tool made for performance improvements of DQL queries (e.g. `SELECT` queries), rather it's a tool for improved data management, such as dropping old partitions of data no longer needed, etc.

Partitioning only divides the data linearly (a search time complexity of `O(n)`). Indexing divides the data logarithmically (in a B-Tree which has a search time complexity of `O(log(n))`), which is exponentially more efficient than Partitioning. So the key you define for Partitioning, you could just define for an Index instead, and it'll already divide your data in a manner that's even quicker to retrieve when `SELECT`ing than Partitioning would provide, generally.